# jQuery mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, with jquery's mouseover. I have an image with a map. When I hover the mouse on specific areas, a div should pop up at the position of the mouse, instead the div pops up at a position according to the scrolling height of the page. [image]

This is when everything goes right.
And the next image shows what happens when I scroll a bit higher.
[image]

The hovered area is the same, but the div is not at the right place. The code I made is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('area').mouseover(function(e){
                   var x = e.clientX;
                   var y = e.clientY;
                   var id = $(this).attr("id");
                   $("div#map-popup-"+id).css({position: "absolute", top: y, left: x});
                   $("div#map-popup-"+id).show();
                   $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                       $("div#map-popup-"+id).hide();
                   });
               }); 
        });
```

I have never worked with maps and areas before, so I don't know what could be messed up. I got a plain html from web archive and I need to restore the site in wordpress. Here is an area from the html code:

```
<img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20160307004818im_/http://dcca.eu/img/chambers_map_new.png" width="1000" height="507" alt="" usemap="#chambers-map" />
<map id="chambers-map" name="chambers-map">
    <area id="ulm" shape="circle" coords="85,160,10" href="#" alt="" />
    <area id="passau" shape="circle" coords="232,136,10" href="#" alt="" />
```

So my question is: why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse cursor's position is based upon it's X and Y co-ordinates on the **page**. You're looking for `pageX` and `pageY`: http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/

So you're probably wanting to `position: fixed;` the element based upon the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`

Answer (score 1):

You want the positioning of pop-up to be relative to your viewport and not to the parent element. Hence use position as 'fixed' instead of 'absolute'.